# PDE - Real Eigensolutions to the Damped Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have been trying to find out how to solve the following problem, but to no avail. Can anybody tell me what to do, hint where to start, or anything that might help?

Find the real eigensolutions to the damped heat equation $u_t=u_{xx}-u$.

Comment: You should specify some boundary conditions. Otherwise, I would try with $u=0$ as a solution...

Comment: the boundary conditions are in part (b.) of the question:
(b.) which solutions satisfy the periodic boundary conditions $u(t,-\pi)=u(t,\pi)$, $u_x(t,-\pi)=u_x(t,\pi)$?
there are no defined boundary conditions for part (a.), so i'm assuming $u(0,x)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform separation of variables:
$$
           u_t +u = u_{xx} \\
              u(t,x)=T(t)X(x) \\
           \frac{T'}{T}+1 = \lambda,\;\; \lambda=\frac{X''}{X} \\
          T(t) = Ce^{(\lambda-1)t},\;\;\; X(x)=A\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+B\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)
$$
You'll need conditions in $x$ to go any further.